# How do I uppercase all strings in a linked list in c?

Tags: c

I'm trying to uppercase all of the strings in a linked list but I am getting a segmentation fault that I can't figure out.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
wordnode_t *upperAll(wordnode_t * indexWords){
    wordnode_t *upperIndexWords = NULL;
    wordnode_t *ptr = indexWords;
    while(ptr){
        char *word = ptr -> w;
        int i = 0;
        for (i=0; word[i]; i++){
            word[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
            }
        upperIndexWords = add_end(indexWords, new_word(word, 0));
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    return upperIndexWords;
}
```

with wordnode_t being a node in the linked list and w the string in the node.

Comment: Assuming that each structure has a "w" that points to a valid string in writable memory, the code shown looks OK except for the call to add_end(), which you don't show us. The only thing I would add is a null pointer check. Any decent debugger should find this in no time.

Comment: 1) How is wordnode_t defined 2) what is the code for add_end?

Comment: In the add_end call shouldn't indexWords be changed to upperIndexWords?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add all declarations and maybe even a short main that you think should work but doesn't?

Comment: Post how the elements of `indexWords` are assigned - the issue lies there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Thank you for for your assistance in what I should include in my questions as well as the answer. It allowed me to figure out the fault and I apologize for the question errors it was my first time posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You get segmentation fault when you are trying to read or write to an address that has not been assigned to your program or is not writable. So obviously, you're program is trying to read memory that is unassigned or not accessible. I believe your `wordnode_t` looks like this:

```
struct wordnode_t{
    char *w;
    wordnode_t *next;
}
```

In this case, you get segfault because this `word[i] = ...` is trying to directly modify the pointer to a string literal `char *word = ptr->w` which is not allowed or simply unmodifiable.

My solution will be to duplicate the `ptr->w` instead of assigning it another name and trying to modify it. Pretty much like this

```
char *word = strdup(ptr->w);
int i = 0;
for (i; word[i]; i++) {
    if (islower(word[i]))
        word[i] = toupper((unsigned char) word[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Or if you are like me and don't like using using functions that much then,

```
char *str = strdup(word);
int i = 0;
while (str[i]) {
    if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) 
        str[i] -= 32;
    i++;
}
```

If you are looking for standard way then avoid `strdup` and be more daring. Use `malloc`

```
#include <string.h>

...

char *word = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr->w) * sizeof(char));;
strcpy(word, ptr->w);
int i = 0;
for (i; word[i]; i++) {
    if (word[i] >= 97 && word[i] <= 122)
        word[i] -= 32;
}
```

Don't forget to `free(word)` when you are done with it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Curious, why use `if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) 
        str[i] -= 32;` instead of something like `if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') 
        str[i] -= 'a' - 'A';`?

Comment: `char *word = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr->w) * sizeof(char));;` is 1-too-small.  Suggest `char *word = malloc(strlen(ptr->w) + 1);`.

Comment: Robust code uses the cast in `toupper((unsigned char) word[i]);` for the same reason it should be used in `if (islower((unsigned char) word[i]))`: to cope with negative values of `word[i]`.

Comment: Imho, `if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) str[i] -= 32;` is cleaner.